# Python: Combine for loop in while loop and iterate rows in a data

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I would like to iterate rows of data and print the final row after reaching a condition. My code looks like this

```
D_sum = 4.39e-05
count = 0
while D_sum < 1:
   for row in df.iterrows():
       count += 1
       D_sum += D_sum
       print('count', count)
       print('D_sum', D_sum)
       print('row', row)
       break  # When i write break the loop is executing correct but, its not printing final row. Its printing first row of data.
```

If I don't write Break, the loop is continuing and ending after certain iterations.

I tried to write this code

```
count = 0
flag = True
while flag:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        count += 1
        D_sum += (df[['Di']].sum()).values
        print('count:', count)
        print('D_sum', D_sum)
        print(row)
if D_sum == 1:
   flag = False
```

But this also continuing until certain iterations (Infinite loop)
Please help me correcting the code in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
D_sum = 4.39e-05
count = 0
for row in df.iterrows():
    count += 1
    D_sum += D_sum
    print('count', count)
    print('D_sum', D_sum)
    # Check your condition here 
    if D_sum >= 1:
       print('row', row)
       break
```